# WP8 App Crashes after localization

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, localization

Recently, I decided to try the [Multilingual App Toolkit](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/multilingual-app-toolkit) in order to add localization support in my already existing WP8 application.

I followed the instructions, it generated the AppResources files for the languages I selected and it was ready to be tested. Unfortunately, every time I deploy the app to my device (tried with emulator too) it instantly crashes without any exception, message or any kind of other information. I tried to clean the project, delete bin and obj folders, disable the languages I added before and the Multilingual App Toolkit with no luck.

I created a new project just with the AppResources files and it worked fine. But, I don't think that the problem is in my code because it doesn't even reach the `App()` method in `App.xaml.cs` file before it crashes.

Anyone knows what's going on?

EDIT:
Does the Resources folder have a size limit?

EDIT 2:
I attached a debugger to the Visual Studio process and when I am running the project on my phone the following exceptions are thrown:

> The thread 0x3d34 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
>
> EnC: Enter Debug Mode: project 'ProjectName'
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in JetBrains.Platform.ReSharper.VisualStudio.Core.dll
>
> The thread 0x1900 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
>
> A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException' occurred in Microsoft.Build.dll
>
> A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> The thread 0x27d0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).

Thanks

Comment: try to check the project properties, start-up objects etc. i've experienced weird application crushes on start up after minor project changes several times and mostly they were related to the project properties, even though I was not updating those.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked everything in the project properties carefully but they seem to be okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by doing what I wanted to avoid most;

I created a completely new project, copied all the files from the old project to the new one ( the localized files too). Everything works fine now.

I think there is something wrong with the ResX Custom Tool which generates the AppResources.Designer.cs file.

Answer (score 2):

first four things I would check is if the AppResources.resx access modifier is public

that the designer is not causing a error.

that the folder is named Resources.

multi lingual app toolkit is enabled in tools menu.

I have never ran into a size issue in the resources folder. I would recommend starting with one language then adding to the list after it is fully functional.

Comment: Well, I have an `Invalid Xaml` error in my Start page which I hadn't before. I tried to delete the whole control (a `LongListSelector`) but that didn't fix it. I read in different questions here that deleting the spaces in the assembly name fixes it, but there are no spaces in my assembly name.

Comment: I have modified my question with more details.

Comment: And I am assuming you have this in app.xaml                                                             <Application.Resources>
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
    </Application.Resources>

Comment: I think the only time I had strange errors to fix I ended up having to delete the designer and rename to like designer1 and then rebuild to overwrite old one. I am curious to see what this ends up being.

Comment: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Yournamespace" this at top of MainPage.xaml? and binding the text like {Binding Path=LocalizedResources.YourTranslationName, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}} I am sure you have these but just in case

Answer (score 1):

That's a very rare problem. Try this: Create a new project with only the AppResources files & try to deploy the project. If the new app crash, then the problem its with the AppResources files; if not, then your problem is in your code.

Comment: Well, as I said the application was fine, and the only change I made in code was to get the string from `AppResources` instead of hardcoding it. I 'll try though. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it and the new project with the AppResources worked fine. I don't think that the problem is my code because it doesn't even reach the App() method in App.xaml.cs file before it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Did you move your localization files to another project or did some name changing?

If so, check [your resource file for English.Designer.cs

and there is code that looks for resources:

```
/// <summary>
        ///   Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Localization.Resources.AppResources", typeof(AppResources).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }
```

In my code, the string `Localicazation.Resources.AppResources` represents Project.Folder.ResourceFiles.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing wrong there. Thanks for your answer though.